# Как поставить таблицу по центру?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Вот [мой сайт](https://websockettest1.000webhostapp.com/index.html). Как отцетрировать таблицу?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так, например:

```
#featured-wrapper table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!